# Xcode 5 Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting setting

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting

In Xcode 5, I create a **project** named **myproject**, in the project's **Build Settings** I can set `Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting` to `YES` in order to use ARC. Then there is a **target** also named **myproject**, what if in the target's **Build Settings** page I set `Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting` to `NO`, does this mean eventually I'll use manual memory management? Do I have to set both of the two boolean flag to the same value, either `YES` for ARC or `NO` for manual memory management?

Comment: target settings will override project settings. SO if you put YES in project settings and NO in target..effectively your boolean value is NO.

Comment: To @TusharKoul, please move your comment to answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project settings will get applied to all your targets. 
Individual target settings will override project settings.

SO if you put YES in project settings and NO in only one particular target..effectively your boolean value is NO for that target. And it'll remain YES for all other targets (where you haven't modified the settings)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both should have the same value (YES or NO). The first is for the project (so xcode warns you when you write code not compatible with arc) and the second in the target settings is for the compiler, so the compiler can add all the retain/release code for you if you have ARC YES.